# How to add background motif in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to add background that has circle like picture below:

And in my Figma, has asset like this:

And my code is like this:

```
Widget buildItem(int index) => Card(
        color: ColorName.brandSecondaryBlue,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
          child: buildItem(),
        ),
      );
```

Anyone else who know how to add it?

Comment: Have you tried Clip widget ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAUebVIb-7s&ab_channel=Flutter

Comment: check `CustomPaint` widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be a clean way but try Using a `Stack` widget and use `Positioned` widget inside.

Here's a sample for what you are trying to achieve.

```
Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 150,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.indigo,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                ),
              ),
              
              Positioned(
                left: -50,
                top: -35,
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  children:
                  [
                    Container(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 150,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
                  ),),
                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.indigo,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
                      ),),

                  ]
                ))
            ],
          ),
        )
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
    import 'dart:ui';
    import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
    import 'package:myapp/utils.dart';
    
    class circlescreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        double baseWidth = 428;
        double fem = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / baseWidth;
        double ffem = fem * 0.97;
        return Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Container(
            // iphone13promax1auq (1:2)
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration (
              color: Color(0xff3241a0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20*fem),
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Container(
                  // ellipse1hmV (1:4)
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0*fem, 0*fem, 237*fem, 272*fem),
                  width: 318*fem,
                  height: 318*fem,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration (
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(159*fem),
                    border: Border.all(color: Color(0xff3c4baf)),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  // ellipse3jCP (1:6)
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0*fem, 0*fem, 0*fem, 113*fem),
                  width: 198*fem,
                  height: 198*fem,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration (
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(99*fem),
                    border: Border.all(color: Color(0xff3c4baf)),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  // ellipse2oi3 (1:5)
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0*fem, 0*fem, 205*fem, 0*fem),
                  width: 318*fem,
                  height: 318*fem,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration (
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(159*fem),
                    border: Border.all(color: Color(0xff3c4baf)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
              );
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: darn! amazing but wouldn't it easier to use SVG? or SVG effect app performance?

Comment: @ChhilyLim Svg image increase app size and performance too

Answer (score 0):

export your figma component with the just the background( purple with circles).

Then add that in assets and use it in the child of Card. So your widget tree would be :

```
Card 
=> 
Container( //with background decoration as image and necessary padding if any
)
 =>
 buildAreaItem()
```

You can also crop the image to get just the top corner ring or play with the fit property in DecorationImage widget.